# How to use gcc from anaconda? When I compile files, it complains about not finding system headers like stdio.h

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm using miniconda to be able to create a portable environment that can can carry it owns dependencies such as GCC within a software application.

I did something some simple like

```
conda install gcc
conda install libgcc
```

and tried using conda's gcc to compile a simple file like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  print('hai world');
}
```

which would complain,

```
fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

I'm doing this within my MacBook and I don't want to install Xcode developer tools to get access to gcc and its system headers because I want this to be as portable as possible.

I also tried conda-build with conda recipes for gcc-4.8, but that ended up complaining that I need cc (C compiler) which comes with Xcode.app that I don't want to install.

Do you have any ideas how to use gcc with system headers through conda so that I can compile files with system headers like stdio.h ?

Comment: Must it be GCC? Personally, I use the Conda Forge stack, i.e., `conda-forge::compilers`. This defines all the environment variables as part of environment activation and let's one use, for example, `$CC hello.c` or `$CXX hello.cpp` in a platform-agnostic way. But this will be GCC on Linux, clang on OS X, and vc (? not sure) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Starting from scratch, install a recent version of miniconda. In particular conda 4.6 switched to a much better SAT solver for the dependency graph.
2. set channel_priority to false (`conda config --set channel_priority false`)
3. Minimize the set of channels.  You probably only REALLY need `defaults` and `conda-forge` (optionally adding a few packages ad hoc from other channels, see below). So you can run `conda config --add channels defaults; conda config --add channels conda-forge`.
4. Avoid having one massive environment for different needs. Instead, create an environment per project/tool.

Your `.condarc` file should look like this:

```
$ cat ~/.condarc
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
channel_priority: disabled
```

If you need to install packages outside of `defaults` and `conda-forge`, you should try installing only them with a channel prefix, and let conda take their dependencies from `defaults` and `conda-forge`, e.g. `conda install bioconda::snakemake`